# get element id on form change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="htdate" id="htdate">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="pgdate" name="pgdate">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I would like get the textbox id when on form change. My js code looks like this:

```
$('form :input').change(function()
{
    var eleID = $(this).id;
    console.log("changeID: ", eleID);
});
```

Console output :

```
changeID:  undefined
```

Is there any ways to get the id of the element during value change.?

Comment: try this `$(this).attr("id")`

Answer (score 4):

*`id` is the property of dom object and jQuery object doesn't have any `id` property, so it will always return `undefined`*

---

Use **[`this.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)** or **[`$(this).attr('id')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get id of the element

```js
$('form :input').change(function() {
  var eleID = this.id;
  // var eleID = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log("changeID: ", eleID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="htdate" id="htdate">
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="pgdate" name="pgdate">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

---

If you want to listen inputting value then use `keypress` , `keyup` or `input` event

```js
$('form :input').on('input', function() {
  var eleID = this.id;
  // var eleID = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log("changeID: ", eleID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="htdate" id="htdate">
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="pgdate" name="pgdate">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @SyafiqAzwan : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

use $().attr();

```
$('form :input').change(function()
{
    var eleID = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log("changeID: ", eleID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any ways to get the id of the element during value change.?*

For this you can use `input` event which is introduced in the `html5`. so this can be done:

```
$('form :input').on('input', function()
{
    var eleID = this.id; // <----this.id; || $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("changeID: ", eleID);
});
```

---

`change` event only gets invoked when you loose focus from the input so if you are looking for immediate effect while `typing/cut-copy-paste` then `input` would be beneficial for you.